# NUnit - Ambiguous message when assert order list

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I created a test case to check a list is sorted or not as below

```
[Test]
public void Request_ShouldReturnOrderedList()
{
    //execute rest request to get json return
    var searchResult = Client.Execute(filterRequest);

    //convert Json to object
    var result = searchResult.ToObject<TheRespose>();
    Assert.That(result.Items, Is.Ordered.By("Text"));
}
```

To be detail, the TheResponse is declare as below

```
public class TheRespose
{
    public int MaxHits;
    public List<Items> Items;
    public int PageIndex;
    public int PageSize;
 }
```

And the Items is declare as below

```
public class Items
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Test case is passed on my local machine (use Visual Studio 2017 with Resharper), however, when run on server (use NUnit3), I got this exception

```
Expected: collection ordered by "Text" But was:  
< <TestCase.Items>, <TestCase.Items>, <TestCase.Items>, <TestCase.Items>, 
<TestCase.Items>, <TestCase.Items>, <TestCase.Items>, 
<TestCase.Items>, <TestCase.Items>, <TestCase.Items>... > 
at TestCase.Test.Request_ShouldReturnOrderedList() 
in G:\RestTest\TestCase\Test.cs:line 112
```

I'm so new with C# and don't know that trouble with this message. What is wrong with my testcase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text ordering is culture-sensitive: one culture might define different ordering rules than another culture. "Text" property is string, and

```
Is.Ordered.By("Text")
```

will compare "Text" properties (to ensure they are sorted) like this:

```
str1.CompareTo(str2);
```

This is the same as

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(str1, str2, CompareOptions.None);
```

So, comparision (and so - ordering) will happen using rules of current culture.

Given your results - it's reasonable to assume that current culture on your development machine is different from culture on server, and so on server test fails, because items are not ordered as expected, according to server culture.

You need to first figure out which culture you are going to use, and then use it for example like this:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // use correct one for your use-case
// note that there are other useful CompareOptions,
// like CompareOptions.StringSort and CompareOptions.IgnoreCase
Assert.That(result.Items, Is.Ordered.Using<string>(culture.CompareInfo.GetStringComparer(CompareOptions.None)).By("Text"));
```

Comment: Thanks Evk for your answer!
Look like this is correct answer, when I introduced new field to "Item" class and try assert its order instead of "Text" (on my machine), then I got same message. I added CultureInfo and it worked.
At last, the message is totally misunderstood and make me confuse so much :).

Comment: Yes, message is not very helpful. It just means collection was expected to be in correct order, but was not.

Comment: Of course, the message would have been clearer if your class included an override of ToString().